# out of memory in xmlspy 2010 professional edition

Tags: xmlspy

My input xml is  3MB file. But, when I apply transformation, an error msg with "Out of Memory" is displayed.

Is any way to increase the memory size.

The m/c I use is 32 bit.

Thank you,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

To increase the available memory, you can close other open applications, background applications in your system tray, and perhaps even some windows services.

Have you tried an alternative means to transform the input xml? Perhaps you can try the free [AltovaXml2011](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) and see if you have the same problems *without* the GUI stuff.

Personally, I think it is just a general PC problem (you just have a low amount of memory plugged in?) and/or the transformation you wish to apply needs to be optimized…